# how to fold by line number in a VS Code Extension?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I am trying to create simple extension for vs code that need to collapse specific cells

I found this option

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.fold', fold={levels: 1, selectionLines: lines});
```

but I cant figure out how to set it to collapse one line (the start of the cell)
how to create the selectionLines argument? (Or a better solution) [there is some extensions that uses editor.foldLevels, editor.foldAll and I can't find the docs for it]

The api:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

you need to do:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.fold', {selectionLines: [lineNumber]});
```